# I think I just messed up everything in developer portal and

Tags: xcode, portal

Just as when I was "validating" my app in Xcode organizer, I have got these two messages:

"The Bundle ID Txxxxxxxxxx.com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx defined in your Xcode Project does not match the Bundle ID that you entered for this app in iTunes Connect xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx."

and

"Application failed code sign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate."

Basically, I just wanted to submit an app that has been rejected by Apple again, but I mess up things by changing developer distribution, provisioning profiles, in fact, I don't even know when I did with the whole uploading process. I am very new to developing, please some experts suggest me what to do will be the best. I will be checking back frequently. Thanks.

Comment: This question has two "Too Localized" close votes so far but, aside from the not clear title, I think the question is good (and I've up-voted it).  Moomoochen messed up his provisioning profile settings and needs help getting back on track.  I think this is a problem that can happen to many developers.

Comment: Why not generate new profiles again and build the app with the new ones? It's worth a shot

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I see you just need to adjust the bundle ID in your XCode project to the ID you entered in iTunes Connect? And then of course sign with the appropiate certificate/provision for this  ID